# Error when loading files in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been trying to load a series of classifiers from scikit-learn that I saved using joblib.dump.  When I load them I am also opening an accompanying file.  When I load all of the files and don't open an accompanying file everything works, but when I do attempt to load the accompanying file I get an error message after exactly 100 files saying operation not permitted on the load operation in joblib.load.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_apply.py", line 74, in <module>
  File "run_apply.py", line 31, in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 407, in load
    file_handle = open(filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/local/Training_features/classifier_50.pkl'
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are not closing files after opening them, and that you have a limit of at most 100 open files? Look at `resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE` (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html )

Comment: I don't believe so. I've done some searching and it seems that there is a different error message when there are too many files open.

Comment: Can't be file permission.  Runs properly when I don't have it simultaneously open a file.

Comment: maybe open an issue at joblib?